# Изменение расположения блоков при уменьшении/увеличении ширины окна браузера

Tags: jquery, css

Есть такая довольно простая структура:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 300px;
  color: #fff;
}
.sidebar, .content {
  min-height: 150px;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  background: #f00;
}
.content{
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #00f;
}
.third-block {
  clear: both;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">Блок 1</div>
  <div class="content">Блок 2</div>
  <div class="third-block">Блок 3</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j7n9yf5q/2/
Необходимо при уменьшении окна до 768px поменять блоки местами - Блок 2 становится на первое место, Блок 3 - за ним, а Блок 1 опускается в самый низ.
Как это реализовать на Jquery?

Comment: на flex-box это реализуется очень легко , надо только лишь указать order для этого и всё , почитайте о flex-box

Comment: Я в курсе, что это делается легко)) Но реализовать нужно на JS))

Comment: на js ? для чего такие такие танцы с бубном ?

Comment: IE9 не поддерживает flexbox

Comment: я не спорю про ie но а arachne не поддерживает css вообще , что теперь под все какашки делать дизайн ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var min_width = 768;
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  var new_width = $(window).width();
  var container = $('.container');
  if (new_width <= min_width && !container.hasClass('compact')) {
    container.addClass('compact');
    $('.sidebar').insertAfter($('.third-block'));
  }
  if (new_width > min_width && container.hasClass('compact')) {
    container.removeClass('compact');
    $('.sidebar').insertBefore($('.content'));
  }
}).trigger('resize');
```

```css
.container {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.sidebar,
.content {
  min-height: 150px;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  background: #f00;
}
.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #00f;
}
.third-block {
  clear: both;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: #0f0;
}
.compact .sidebar {
  float: none;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">Блок 1</div>
  <div class="content">Блок 2</div>
  <div class="third-block">Блок 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А как быть если у меня останется два блока - sidebar и content?

Comment: Заменить `$('.sidebar').insertAfter($('.third-block'));` на `$('.sidebar').insertAfter($('.content'));`

Comment: Спасибо, уже в принципе разобрался, сделав так: $('.sidebar').insertAfter($('.container > div:last-child'));

Answer (score 1):

А зачем это делать именнно на js? можете воспользоваться медиа запросами в css для разных расширений

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {/*тут нужные стили*/}
```

Comment: Нужно изменить структуру DOM - как я это на CSS сделаю? Flexbox-ы мне не подходят